# Chef recommended way for executing a command

Tags: linux, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I was trying to run a command `mkdir -p /path/on/disk && touch sample-file` using chef. My chef code is as below. I am on linux.

```
execute 'create directory' do
    command 'mkdir -p /path/on/disk && touch sample-file'
end
```

Is there a more beter way to achieve this using chef?

Comment: There are the [`directory`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_directory.html) and [`file`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_file.html) resources. You should be able to do the remaining math on your own.

Comment: @StephenKing Yes but I want to create the file only when "/path/on/disk" disk exists and if not then don't create the file. How will I achieve that from what you have showed me above in links?

Comment: But that's different from what your above command does.

Comment: You can [guard](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#guards) particular resources, `file` in your case, to only apply, if the directory exists (`only_if do ::File.directory?('/path/on/disk') end `).

Comment: @StephenKing Want to copy this down to an answer instead?

Comment: @coderanger I'm not sure what the OP wants. The provided command shell doesn't create the file only if the directory exists? All that doesn't make lot of sense to me.

Comment: @StephenKing Forget about the condition "create the file only if the directory exists" just create the code in the answer how I will execute just to create the directory and the file.

Comment: Seriously? Creating a directory and a file, that's all?

Comment: Yes I am new to Chef so it is a big deal for me :)

Comment: Please follow a tutorial, e.g. on [learn.chef.io](https://learn.chef.io/tutorials/learn-the-basics/).

Comment: I am taking that tutorial only one of my mentor gave me this example and asked me to show another way I will write that in Chef. :)

Comment: Dude, it feels like you're a StackOverflow newbie..(which you aren't).
Don't ask for copy & paste solutions, it contradicts with learning that thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite your laziness, here's something similar to the thing you want to achieve (your question is very unclear).

```rb
directory "/path/on/disk" do
  recursive true
end

file "/path/on/disk/sample-file" do
  content ""
  action :create_if_missing
end
```